# Django: EmailMessage not raising exception when only one of two recipients fail

Tags: python, django, smtplib

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from smtplib import SMTPException
try:
    email = EmailMessage(subject, body, "noreply@myserver.com.br", recipients)
    email.content_subtype = 'html'
    email.send(fail_silently=False)
except SMTPException as e:
    print e.recipients
```

If I set `recipients = ["foo@myserver.com.br"]`, the server responds with a "unknown user" message, and the exception is raised.

But if I set `recipients = ["foo@myserver.com.br", "bar@myserver.com.br"]`, the message is delivered to bar@myserver.com.br, which is an existing user, but no exception is raised because of foo being an unexistent user.

Is there a way to raise the exception if at least one of the recipients fails?